# Mapping two fields to the same column with the EclipseLink API

Tags: eclipselink

**Hi,**

I am using the **EclipseLink API** to create dynamic entities to represent a graph stored in database tables. The links are stored in their own table, which contains a link ID column, the start node ID and the end node ID columns, plus other user-defined columns. The nodes have their own table, where a node ID is stored plus other user-defined columns.

When doing the mapping from the links table to the nodes table I am doing this with the API:

```
OneToOneMapping startNodeMapping = dynamicLinkTypeBuilder.addOneToOneMapping("startNode", dynamicNodeTypeBuilder.getType(), "NODE_ID");     
OneToOneMapping endNodeMapping = dynamicLinkTypeBuilder.addOneToOneMapping("endNode", dynamicNodeTypeBuilder.getType(), "NODE_ID");
```

When running the previous code I receive the following message in the stack trace:

```
Local Exception Stack: Exception [EclipseLink-48] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: Multiple writable mappings exist for the field [TEST_NETWORK_LINK.NODE_ID].  Only one may be defined as writable, all others must be specified read-only.
Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.OneToOneMapping[startNodeId]
```

This exception is thrown because I am mapping two fields (startNode and endNode) from the same entity to the same column/field in a different table/entity.

Do you know what could I do in order to solve this mapping problem? Would you suggest a different strategy? I cannot change the tables structure and I don't want to make one of the mappings "read only", but I am free to change the dynamic mappings.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is as the error message states - you are using the "NODE_ID" field as a foreign key in both the startNode and endNode mappings.  Essentially your object's startNode will always == the endNode when read back from the database.  I believe you will want to specify different fields for the two mappings if they are meant to reference different nodes, so that they use their own foreign key.  eg:

OneToOneMapping startNodeMapping = dynamicLinkTypeBuilder.addOneToOneMapping("startNode", dynamicNodeTypeBuilder.getType(), "START_NODE_ID");
OneToOneMapping endNodeMapping = dynamicLinkTypeBuilder.addOneToOneMapping("endNode", dynamicNodeTypeBuilder.getType(), "END_NODE_ID");

Both will automatically reference the primary key in the referenced table, which I assume is "NODE_ID".

Comment: I see, I overlooked that detail, I was trying to use the column name used in the Node table instead of the foreign key names in the Link table. Thank you for catching that error in my code!